# Different Azure services for WordPress hosting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

maybe I should start that I am pretty new with Azure and I want to apologize in advance if my question is stupid. I am currently looking into the option to move my WordPress website to Azure. However, as I was looking through the pre-configured templates, I am quite confused and would be really thankful if someone can explain this for me. (Thank you in advance).

The template, which was created by WordPress for WordPress is using "App Service" model with a tier plan S1 (which comes with 100 total ACU & 1.75GB memory) and according to rough estimate it should be around 75 USD per month.

However, an alternative template created by Cloud Infrastructure Services is using a virtual machine model with a tier plan Standard_B1ms (which comes with 1 vcpu & 2 GiB memory) and according to rough estimate it should be around 36.83 USD per month.

I am quite struggling to understand the difference between the two options and more particular why one is using "App Service" and the other "Virtual Machine". In addition, what are the benefits and disadvantages to use one over the other. For example, when it comes to spikes in website traffic, the need to upgrade to higher tier, reliability, etc. Furthermore, I am not sure what 100 total ACU means. Is this supposed to be more powerful than the output that comes from a 1 core v-cpu? If yes, how much more? Last but not least, would like to hear your general opinion on hosting WordPress website on Azure, as well as, which of the two options would you go with and why? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ACU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu) is a made-up measure for estimating the amount of computing power you receive. The ACU is a type of estimator since certain processors have turbo boost and some don't. DTUs for Azure SQL are similar, where DTU is a made-up statistic that combines IOPS, CPU, and RAM.

Azure App Service as "Build, deploy, and scale web apps on a fully managed platform". It's a Platform as a service and hence would be managed in the containers or any operating system can be used. Use the fully managed platform for your operating and monitoring activities to meet stringent, enterprise-grade performance, security, and compliance requirements.

Azure Virtual Machine It provides on-demand, high-scale, secure, virtualized infrastructure. It provides the flexibility of virtualization for a wide range of computing solutions, including development and testing, application execution, and datacenter expansion. It's the flexibility of open-source software set to your specifications.

Hence, Azure App service has lots of advantages as it has got tools with which it can be integrated. Scaling up is an ability using  both the services and if you have an fix budget then you can opt Azure Virtual Machines then resize it anytime.
Here, is the [Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?OCID=AID2200195_SEM_ab444158ffd21011354720479ebf57a1:G:s&ef_id=ab444158ffd21011354720479ebf57a1:G:s&msclkid=ab444158ffd21011354720479ebf57a1) which might help you to calculate the exact expenditure according the resources you choose.

I would definitely suggest to go for Azure App Service as it has a wide range of advantages.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I really appreciate it. At the end I decided to try both. On the App service side I used a template which was created by the WordPress team and on the virtual machine side I went and set up an Ubuntu server and from there installed everything manually (php, mysql, apache, wordpress, etc). Oddly enough, the template I used was linked to a GitHub repository which hasn't been updated in two years. That said, after the setup process was completed I was prompted to update my wordpress, themes and plugins and everything went very smoothly.

Comment: At the end, I was running the same version of WordPress with the same theme and the same addons. The result of both was pretty satisfying as I got quite good loading speeds. That said, the virtual machine was pulling slightly ahead in performance compared to the app service. That and in combination of the price, which was half compared to my daily costs for the app service I decided to go with the virtual machine. As it would also give me some deeper insights how to manage my server.

Comment: PS: I think, I should also add that I am no where near the expertise level to be sure that the test I conducted were identical. Therefore, the slightly better performance from the virtual machine might have been due to some external factors.

Comment: Aw, that's quite a cool information, Thank you so much @GeorgeSmith. Yes, VM(s) are lot more cheaper in comparison to Azure App Service.